# How to disable body scrolling when a particular button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a HTML page with menu & content.

Everything is working fine for desktop, but when menu is clicked in mobile, the content of the body overlaps with menu items when scrolled (when menu is scrolled, the content is also scrolling).

I tried using `overflow: hidden` and  `position:fixed`,
but it is making entire page non-scrollable, even when the button is not clicked.

Can anyone please help me with this ?

I tried the following :

My JS :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mobile-toggle").click(function () {
        $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden'); 
    });
});
```

My button :

```
<button id="mobile-toggle" class="mobile-toggle">
    _('mobile-toggle')<span></span>
</button>
```

It is disabling scrolling when clicked, but it's not working on mobile.

Comment: Adding a z-index that is higher than the current overlapping items might help.

Comment: To avoid overlapping you could set your menu as "fixed" position with "top: 0px", so will fixed at the top (if it must stay at the top) and will not flow, and then add depth, "z-index: 999999 "exaggerating ...

Comment: It is not with Menu its with content when scrolling menu the content is also scrolling

Answer (score 0):

You need to rework your css so that it is responsive - here would be a good start [Responsive Design](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try to target the `html` element with your selector too:

```
$('body,html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
```